# Color rows in Outlook 2007 mail blotter

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007

I am receiving lots of mail each day, but there are some mails, which I don't much care about, like notifications, etc.

I would like to change row font color by filter. E.g. make it grey for all mails from non-important-stuff@example.com.

Is it doable in MS Outlook 2007?

Comment: This can be done in "Conditional Formatting" in the "View Settings" option. A set of filters can be created for color a specific emails. Please refer the link for more details: http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/outlook-help/automatically-change-incoming-message-colors-and-fonts-based-on-sender-subject-or-recipients-HA102054868.aspx

Comment: Yes, I do this all the time. @vembutech, why don't you make your comment into an answer.